# Leaked window error with Progress Dialog even after calling dismiss

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, progressdialog

I have a menu button, that when I click it, it sends some data to the cloud. While it is sending the data, I display a progress dialog. Every thing goes swimmingly and seems to be fine and I can press the button as many times as I want and the data is properly sent to the cloud.
But when I go to exit the activity I get a error saying that there was a window leak:

```
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{4321fd38 V.E..... R......D 0,0-1026,288} that was originally added here
```

the "here" is referring to when I insatiate my progress dialog.

Here is my code:

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(CruiseDetailRollCallActivity.this, "", "Loading...", true);//set up & show progress dialog

switch(item.getItemId()){
case R.id.menu_roll_call_opt_in:
    //saveing something into Parse -- (a database online, check Parse.com if you want more info, but just treat this like I am saving something into the cloud)
    currentUser.put("somethingBoolean", false); 
    currentUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback(){

    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) { //once data has been put into the cloud
        progressDialog.dismiss();//dismiss the dialog
        supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();//refreshes the options menu
    }
    });

    return true;

default:
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

I should mention that this is not crashing my application but merely displaying the error. I have no clue why it is happening, and I feel like I shouldn't just ignore it.

**EDIT**: found my mistake. It was failing because works was because I was hitting back on the action bar and the progress dialog would be created but never dismissed since it was only being dismissed inside the done code.

Comment: you should dismiss `Progress Dialog` in `onStop().`

Comment: @SimplePlan See my comment on your answer below. onStop() is killable and depending on what the OS decides to do, onStop() may never be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was failing because works was because I was hitting back on the action bar and the progress dialog would be created but never dismissed since it was only being dismissed inside the done code.

I moved

```
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(CruiseDetailRollCallActivity.this, "", "Loading...", true);//set up & show progress dialog
```

into

```
case R.id.menu_roll_call_opt_in:
//saveing something into Parse -- (a database online, check Parse.com if you want more info, but just treat this like I am saving something into the cloud)
currentUser.put("somethingBoolean", false); 
currentUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback(){

@Override
public void done(ParseException e) { //once data has been put into the cloud
    progressDialog.dismiss();//dismiss the dialog
    supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();//refreshes the options menu
}
});

return true;
```

so looks something like this

```
case R.id.menu_roll_call_opt_in:
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(CruiseDetailRollCallActivity.this, "", "Loading...", true);//set up & show progress dialog
//saveing something into Parse -- (a database online, check Parse.com if you want more info, but just treat this like I am saving something into the cloud)
currentUser.put("somethingBoolean", false); 
currentUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback(){

@Override
public void done(ParseException e) { //once data has been put into the cloud
    progressDialog.dismiss();//dismiss the dialog
    supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();//refreshes the options menu
}
});

return true;
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you're leaking the activity into the `currentUser` object, when you pass the `CruiseDetailRollCallActivity` into `currentUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback()...`. The `SaveCallback` class that you just created now has a strong reference to the Activity. It will never be garbage collected, even though you exit the method. You should use a `WeakReference` and then it can be garbage collected.

```
WeakReference<CruiseDetailRollCallActivity> weakRef = new WeakReference<CruiseDetailRollCallActivity>(CruiseDetailRollCallActivity.this)
```

Then, pass the weakRef in to the ProgressDialog constructor:

```
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(weakRef.get(), "", "Loading...", true);
```

Whenever you're passing around the Context in Android, check to see if you need a WeakReference so it can be garbage collected. It's easy to leak the entire application.

Comment: I don't fully understand this because I run a similar code elsewhere in my app and it doesn't throw the error. But your code did work.

Comment: You should fix all the other code then. You're causing a memory leak on devices. People won't buy your app! :)

Comment: I wrote a blog post about this problem. It's worth your time to learn about WeakReferences and garbage collection, especially if you will be working with Android. The system is basically architected to produce memory leaks. And it seems to be coming up a lot on SO in the last few days. You can read a longer explanation here: http://tmblr.co/ZSJA4p13azutu

Comment: Edit: my mistake, it might be actually working. need to double check something.

Comment: found my mistake. The reason it was giving me that error was not because of what you mentioned above (although I should look at the blog post and take it into consideration). It was failing because works was because I was hitting back on the action bar and the progress dialog would be created but never dismissed since it was only being dismissed inside the done code. I will still mark your answer as right because people should probably be handling it like this.

Comment: @Sree Thanks for the karma points but I think it would be best if you turned your comment into an answer and accepted your own answer. You did the work to figure out the problem; SO will be better for it.